# Как клонировать на сервер?

Tags: github, клиент-сервер

Добрый вечер.

Очень нравится работа github. Пока научился делать клоны на локальных компьютерах с помощью их программы (выхожу с window).

Пожалуйста, подскажите как работать с сервером? Т.е. чтобы все изменения, сделанные на локальном компьютере, обновились на сервере и обратная ситуация: изменения на сервере были отражены на локальном.

Спасибо.

Comment: > т.е. чтобы все имения сделанные на локальном компьютере обновились на сервере и обратная ситуация: изменения на сервере были отражены на локальном.

git - это не тулза для синхронизации файлов. Можно поставить ежеминутный крон, но вы сами потом об этом пожалеете.

**Изменения на сервере не должны попадать на локальную машину и в git вообще, в идеале их и быть-то на сервере не должно.** Гит, конечно, очень гибкая штуковина и позволяет осуществить вышеописанное, но вам оно не нужно, поверьте. А для выкатывания апдейтов с локалки на сервер достаточно поставить крон/гит-хук.

Comment: Что такое "крон/гит-хук"? И где об этом можно прочитать подробнее?

Comment: @Максим147б крон - это стандартный linux-планировщик, который позволяет выполнять задачи в заданные промежутки времени, довольно часто его ставят ежеминутно проверять наличие каких-то задач, типа тех же обновлений. Хуки - это вызываемые по тому или иному событию скрипты репозитория, подробнее в официальной документации http://git-scm.com/book/ru/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-Git-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-Git

Answer (score 1):

Найдите силы [прочитать](http://git-scm.com/book/ru/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-Git) основы работы с git. Все очень популярно описано и с примерами.